# application that built in gwt not good shown in mobile

Tags: css, gwt, mgwt

I built application in gwt to mobile and I have some bugs that i can not fixed them
1) I have textBox in the bottom of screen and when i click on textBox the virtual Keyboard open and hide the textBox
this is css code of textBox

```
 border: 0 none;
float: right;
width: 80%;
background-color: #F0F0F4;
color: #00AEEF;
padding-bottom: 2%;
padding-top: 2%;
```

and this is screenshot of state screen
1)
http://i250.photobucket.com/albums/gg253/gallavie/Screenshot_2014-09-05-00-56-44_zps6303037b.png
2)
http://i250.photobucket.com/albums/gg253/gallavie/Screenshot_2014-09-05-00-56-19_zps9f3a133a.png
3)
http://i250.photobucket.com/albums/gg253/gallavie/Screenshot_2014-09-05-00-56-37_zps6e212af5.png
4)
http://i250.photobucket.com/albums/gg253/gallavie/Screenshot_2014-09-05-00-56-44_zps6303037b.png
thank you

Comment: You should split this question into 3 separate questions and provide some code. We cannot help you without looking at your code.

Comment: ok you right I divide my questions so I start with first question keyboard hide the textBox I update my question  thank you

Answer (score 0):

@user2320349 answer to your question:1)--
Why dont u make some adjustments to your viewport. see

```
MGWTSettings settings =  MGWTSettings.getAppSetting();
ViewPort viewPort = settings.getViewPort();
viewPort.setHeightToDeviceHeight();
viewPort.setWidthToDeviceWidth();
viewPort.setUserScaleAble(false).setMinimumScale(1.0).setMinimumScale(1.0).setMaximumScale(1.0);
viewPort.setTargetDensity(DENSITY.MEDIUM);
settings.setViewPort(viewPort);
MGWT.applySettings(settings);
```

use this code in your onModuleLoad(). It pushes the view to upside when keyboard is fired.So you can see your text field while text is taking from keyboard.